# Отловить ошибку раньше браузера

Tags: javascript

В общем, тема в следующем:
У меня есть код, который выполняется с помощью eval.

Как можно извратиться, чтобы если **при выполнении** кода возникает ошибка - я мог отловить ее примерно так же, как ее ловит тот же Firebug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простите, глюкануло. Забыло я про try и catch :)
Вопрос снят.

P.S. Для того, кто 1-ку влепил :))

```
try{
    eval(code)
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```